# Clojure seq? test not working in function with if

Tags: if-statement, clojure, seq

I have created this function make-seq. That if passed a seq list like '(true false) it returns it as is, but if passed a single false it returns (false).

```
(defn make-seq [data] (if seq? data) data (list data))
```

For some reason it always evaluates as false the if check.

```
(make-seq '(true false))

 => ((true false))

(make-seq true)
 => (true)
```

Not sure why it is doing that as running on the repl it works the test.

```
 (seq? '(true false))

  => true
```

Any reason why the defn make-seq logic is not working in the if?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, your `make-seq` function is basically throwing away the `(if seq? data)` and `data` expressions, and only returning the final `(list data)`.

You're missing an open-parens, and a close-parens for balance.

```
;                         ⌄                            ⌄
(defn make-seq [data] (if (seq? data) data (list data)))
```

Clojure linting tools like `eastwood` and `kibit` can help you detect misuses such as your original version of `make-seq` where you discard expressions, which could make sense if those expressions had side-effects, but yours don't.

Answer (score 1):

The if-statement syntax needed correction:

```
(defn make-seq [data] (if (seq? data) data (list data)))

(make-seq '(true false))
=> (true false) 

(make-seq true)
=> (true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, I would also suggest using indentation. Even for simple expressions like this, it helps the eye to recognize things faster & more reliably:

```
(defn make-seq
  [data]
  (if (seq? data)
    data
    (list data)))

(make-seq '(true false))     => (true false)
(make-seq   true)            => (true)
```